# Adding data to a Data Extension by using Collect Code

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, code, web

I am researching for the best way to do this:

- Capture abandoned cart information from website
- Fire journey with data captured from abandoned cart

As far as I know, we can use Collect Code `(<script type="text/javascript" src="//7289990.collect.igodigital.com/collect.js"></script>)`

Where "7289990" is the MID of our instance, right?

And insert the necessary additional code in any website section that has a shopping cart:

```
<script>
  _etmc.push(["setOrgId", "7289990"]);
  _etmc.push(["trackCart", { "cart": [
    {"item" : "INSERT_PRODUCT_CODE", "quantity":  "INSERT_QUANTITY", "price" : "INSERT_PRICE", "unique_id" : "INSERT_UNIQUE_ID" },
    {"item" : "INSERT_PRODUCT_CODE", "quantity":  "INSERT_QUANTITY", "price" : "INSERT_PRICE", "unique_id" : "INSERT_UNIQUE_ID" }
  ]}]);
</script>
```

My doubts are:

- Will this information be added to a Data Extension I specify?
- How do I specify that I want to capture additional data such as First and Last name, or other custom fields into the DE?